# Is there any program where you can take notes on a PDF and export those as pointers to the original document?

Tags: 16.04, pdf, notes

I've tried like 4-5 programs today and none of them are working.

Mendeley - has the option to export notes, but doesn't actually create a file (a bug)

Nixnote - can't take notes on PDF

Xournal - can't export notes as separate index

Zotero - can't take notes on PDF

Document Viewer - can't take notes on PDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you may try [FoxitReader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/downloads/) (I use it on daily basis without any problem), they offer a free version with multiple features.

As described in their website

> Small, fast, and feature-rich PDF viewer that allows you to open, view, and print any PDF file. Unlike other free readers, it enables you to create PDFs, participate in a shared review, and more. Now available with ConnectedPDF technology.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question to change the focus from recommendations to fixing mendeley. But if this works, I will revert and accept.

Comment: Thanks. Everything was working swimmingly up until a point - after I pushed my document to connectedpdf I could see the AreaHighlight I made, but not the text of the comment. I send a bug report to them.